# unable to put values in vector with the same syntax as array

Tags: c++

i tried to put values into the vector using the same method as i would with an array but it seems that it doesn't work when i remember being told in class that i can do it the same way. was i told wrong or is it that my code is wrong?

my code:

```
vector<int> test ;
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    test[i] = i;
}
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    cout << test[i] << " ";
}
```

i am also facing an issue where when i run the code it doesn't do what i am hoping for it to do.

Comment: Change `vector<int> test ;` to `vector<int> test(5) ;`. There's no automatic allocation using the `operator[](size_t)`.

Comment: @user0042 thank you

Comment: Vectors are not arrays. If you want to append something to a vector, use push_back(). `test.push_back(i)` in this case. This will make sure that the vector is resized automatically to allocate space for the new elements you're appending.

Comment: @Drt it is possible that my memory is not standing by my side on this issue and i am remembering the discussion in the class wrong. but i remember discussing that it can be used the same way we use arrays

Comment: By the way; please remember that there's also the option of using `std::array` if you don't need to dynamically change the size.

Comment: @JesperJuhl i understand that, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error with the initialization of your vector. Since the vector of yours is empty, trying to assign values at indexes of the vector is not possible. The corrected code would be:

```
vector<int> test(5);
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    test[i] = i;
}
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    cout << test[i] << " ";
}
```

As you can see above, the vector `test` has a size of 5, which can now be filled using indexes.

On the other hand, you could also have changed the first part of your code to:

```
vector<int> test;
test.reserve(5);
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    test.push_back(i);
}
```

since now you are actually *adding* values to the vector, instead of just assigning non existent array positions. [`reserve()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) increases the capacity of a `vector` to a given amount.

Comment: i understand i can use .push_back, but i wanted to learn how i can make this way work. thank you so much for putting the time and replying

Comment: If you feel the answer is correct, then please mark it as so by clicking the green checkmark icon below the downvote button.

Comment: (not the down voter) You're doing double work.  You should call reserve and then use `push_back`/`emplace_back`.

Comment: @NathanOliver That seems to be extremely unnecessary given the circumstances. Wouldn't calling `push_back` reserve the space automatically after the first call?

Comment: Maybe for this OP but your answer is not just for the OP, it is for all the other people that find this.  Might as well give something everyone can use and is efficient.

Comment: @NathanOliver read my comment edit. I seem to be a bit fuzzy with `push_back`, since I thought it automatically allocated memory after the first call.

Comment: `push_back` just grows the vector by a fixed amount (normally twice the current capacity).  So your example is going to have 3 reallocations and copying elements to the new buffers.  A call to `reserve` at the beginning gives you a buffer that never needs to be reallocated.

Comment: `.resize()` is also an option you could mention for completeness.

Answer (score 1):

`vec[i]` does not allocate space, it presumes the space is already there.

Either you need to preallocate the vector, like so:

```
std::vector<int> test; //I avoid the constructor that takes a size, because I don't trust it
test.resize(5);

for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    test[i] = i;
}
```

Or you need to use one of the methods that explicitly performs an allocation:

```
std::vector<int> test;

for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    test.emplace_back(i);
    //OR: test.push_back(i); //Will not work for un-movable objects, like std::mutex
    //OR: test.insert(test.end(), i);
}
```

Comment: "I avoid the constructor that takes a size, because I don't trust it" - huh? On what grounds?  That's one of the silliest things I've read all day..

Comment: Your second example could really use a call to `reserve`.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Because what, exactly, does `std::vector<int> test{5};` do? Because it doesn't allocate a vector of size 5, it allocates a vector of size 1 with the sole value of 5. I've encountered too many mistakes caused by that ambiguity that I just explicitly resize afterwards instead of putting it in the constructor. It might seem silly, and maybe it is, but it saves me my sanity, which is, as far as I'm concerned, the most precious resource a programmer has.